# HTML/CSS - parentheses instead of period/full stop for all ordered lists/items

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Is there a way using CSS to change the ordered list item style globally, including nested lists, to brackets/parentheses instead of full stops/periods?

```
<ol type="1">
    <li>Main list number one.</li>
    <li>Main list number two.</li>
        <ol type="a">
            <li>Sublist first.</li>
            <li>Sublist second.</li>
        </ol>
    <li>Main list number three.</li>
</ol>
<ol type='I'>
    <li>Upper roman list one.</li>
    <li>Upper roman list one.</li>
</ol>
```

Produces:

```
(1)  Main list number one.
(2)  Main list number two.
    (a)  Sublist first.
    (b)  Sublist second.
(3)  Main list number three.
(I)  Upper roman list one.
(II) Upper roman list two.
```

I'm not too fussed about supporting older/obscure browsers - if it works in the latest version of Chrome, that'll do for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define custom [`list-style-type`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type) with [`@counter-style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@counter-style). In the following example, I extended the built-in list styles that correspond the the `type`s you've used to surround the counter with parentheses.

```css
@counter-style paren-decimal {
  system: extends decimal;
  prefix: "(";
  suffix: ") ";
}

@counter-style paren-lower-alpha {
  system: extends lower-alpha;
  prefix: "(";
  suffix: ") ";
}

@counter-style paren-upper-roman {
  system: extends upper-roman;
  prefix: "(";
  suffix: ") ";
}

[type="1"] {
  list-style: paren-decimal;
}

[type="a"] {
  list-style: paren-lower-alpha;
}

[type="I"] {
  list-style: paren-upper-roman;
}
```

```html
<ol type="1">
    <li>Main list number one.</li>
    <li>Main list number two.</li>
        <ol type="a">
            <li>Sublist first.</li>
            <li>Sublist second.</li>
        </ol>
    <li>Main list number three.</li>
</ol>
<ol type='I'>
    <li>Upper roman list one.</li>
    <li>Upper roman list one.</li>
</ol>
```